# Check if variable equals open parenthesis

Tags: shell-script, test

I'm currently trying to figure this out.

```
if [ $CHAR == ( ]
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. So how do I force it to do what I obviously intended?

(For bonus points, how do I get the comparison to work in a `case` block?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need quotes

```
if [ "$CHAR" == "(" ]
```

You can do similar with `case`

```
case $CHAR in
  '(') # do stuff
```

Comment: Huh. I already did that, and it didn't work. It seems there was a second, unrelated syntax error on the same line that also involved brackets. How unlucky!

Comment: Double or single `=` in `[ ... ]`?

Comment: It doesn't matter, in this case.  `bash` (and `ksh`) accepts both.

Comment: No reason to double quote the parenthesis in the first example

Comment: In order for questions like this to not be asked again, ask a general question ("How can I write a special character as a normal one?") (I'll do the job)

Comment: @StevenPenny The `(` needs quoting; `'` or `"` (or even `\(`) doesn't matter, here.   I tend to use `"` in this sort of test for symmetry (unless I specifically have a `$` that I want to keep untouched :-)).